# Owncloud: How does each Federated Cloud ID generated?

Tags: owncloud

Owncloud has Federated Cloud id for more information(https://owncloud.org/federation/).

As an example Federated Cloud ID:

```
ee14ea28-b869-1036-8080-9dbd8c6b1579@b2drop.eudat.eu 
3d8e2dc2-b855-1036-807f-9dbd8c6b1579@b2drop.eudat.eu 
  col1   col2 col3 col4  col5
```

**[Q]** How does each `Federation Cloud ID` generated? Is there any pattern or some algorithm to generate each columns?

For example:

- Could we conclude that all ends with `9dbd8c6b1579`,
- Does dash (`-`) is generated on the same pattern?

On the example as you can see third and fifth columns are same for two different `Federation Cloud ID` and third column formed by all digits. Is it true for all `Federation Cloud ID`s?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a [RFC-4122 V1 UUID](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4122) (internal username) coming from your connected LDAP server. Normally the Federated Cloud ID is generated by joining the unique `<username>` together with the `<server_url>` of your instance, but in some old versions of oC the LDAP UUID was used instead.

EDIT: It's indeed a well known technical limitation; you can track it down in https://github.com/owncloud/core/issues/23412 and https://github.com/owncloud/core/issues/29503 as a feasible future solution.

Comment: I am using eudat-b2drop: https://b2drop.eudat.eu/login I am not sure which owncloud server version they are using @Alfageme

Comment: By looking at https://b2drop.eudat.eu/status.php it looks like they're using NextCloud version 11.0.3 - You might want to get a look at this issue https://github.com/nextcloud/server/issues/5406 for explanation and more info. Also, I was wrong, hasn't been "fixed" in oC 9.x. Creating a federated share with an LDAP user is not that user-friendly nowadays.

Comment: I am just using this web-site "https://b2drop.eudat.eu/", it automatically creates me a federation-cloud it, I am not sure its version. I realize all ends with  `9dbd8c6b1579 ` is it normal that all federation-ids will end this with this string patter?  @Alfageme

Comment: Nope, as commented in the original answer; that federation-cloud-id is tied to an LDAP UUID (unique identifier). If follows the structure defined in https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4530#section-2.1 i.e. 16 octets encoded as a URN; where last 12 digits correspond to the "node" part: https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4122#section-4.1.6 (which generation varies depending on the version their LDAP implements)

Comment: How about generated dashes? After first 8th character and later after each 4 characters there is a dash generated, does it occur same for all federation-cloud id generated via b2drop.eudat.eu? Maybe  b2drop.eudat.eu tied to string `9dbd8c6b1579`? @Alfagame.

Comment: Yes, dashes are part of the formal definition of UUID and are always placed after the same octets. And as said, the "node" part of the string might be shared between users in the same LDAP server (e.g. the first version of the UUID consisted on the MAC address of the server)

Comment: When I remove the dashes, the Federation cloud-id it became 32 bytes! That was the size I want to obtain. So as I understand I can store the string without its dashes and after I receive the string I can put the dashed after the its constant octet locations. @Alfageme

Comment: What are you trying to achieve by manipulating the federation ids if I may ask. Note that you should not rely on the last part to be always the same even for the same LDAP server (the UUIDs could e.g. have been dumped from different old servers)

Comment: Only discarding dashes will fix my problem to make it 32 bytes. I need to store the string on ethereum blockchain where storing string is expensive and it has been recommended to store strings as 32 bytes. So I am trying to reduce the size of  the federated cloud id where I could obtain its original format from its reduced case. For example since I know the dash locations as you mentioned, I can add them to its reduced case. @Alfageme